# Universal references and std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

In his "C++ and Beyond 2012: Universal References" presentation, Scott repeatedly stresses the point, that *universal references* handle/bind to everything and thus overloading a function that already takes a universal reference parameter does not make sense.
I had no reason to doubt that until I mingled them with `std::initializer_list`.

Here is a short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void foo(T&&) { cout << "universal reference" << endl; }

template <typename T>
void foo(initializer_list<T>) { cout << "initializer list" << endl; }

template <typename T>
void goo(T&&) { cout << "universal reference" << endl; }

template <typename T>
void goo(initializer_list<T> const&) { cout << "initializer list" << endl; }

int main(){
    auto il = {4,5,6};
    foo( {1,2,3} );
    foo( il );
    goo( {1,2,3} );
    goo( il );
    return 0;
}
```

Oddly enough, VC11 Nov 2012 CTP complains about ambiguity (`error C2668: 'foo' : ambiguous call to overloaded function`). Yet even more suprising is, that gcc-4.7.2, gcc-4.9.0 and clang-3.4 agree on the following output:

```
initializer list
initializer list
initializer list
universal reference
```

So apparently it is possible (with gcc and clang) to overload functions taking universal references with `initializer_list`s but when using the `auto + { expr } => initializer_list`-idiom it does even matter whether one takes the `initializer_list` by value or by `const&`.
At least to me that behavior was totally surprising.
Which behavior conforms to the standard? Does anyone know the logic behind that?

Comment: The last one is an example of [over.ics.rank]/3 sub-bullet 6, stating that the overload whose parameter type is less cv-qualified will be used unambiguously.

Comment: Are you sure there was a statement in the presentation as general as you claim? It's true that a universal reference will bind to anything, but it's obviously not true that the overload disambiguation mechanism (for templates, that is) will always rank the universal-reference one as the most specific overload.

Comment: Skipping briefly through the slides, on slide 17 it says: `Overloading + URef almost always an error. Makes no sense: URefs handle everything. [...]`

Comment: @user2523017 Ok. The rules used to rank template overloads are not easy to understand. I could be wrong (although Xeo's answer seems to agree), but I'd have assumed naturally that `template <class T> void f(initializer_list<T>)` is more specialized than `template <class T> void f(T&&)`. Simple tests with GCC seem to confirm this too (not necessarily using `initializer_list` as container).

Comment: @jogojapan It is true that `template <class T> void f(initializer_list<T>)` is more specialized than `template <class T> void f(T&&)` but the crux is *it doesn't care*. Overload selection *first* ranks based on the conversion sequence, then **if there's no best overload yet** on some other criteria including partial ordering ("more specialized").

Comment: Check out my article on this topic here: http://mortoray.com/2013/06/03/overriding-the-broken-universal-reference-t/

Comment: @DyP I might misunderstand parts of what you are saying, but I have a suspicion that you confuse ordinary function overload resolution (§13.3) with function template overload resolution (§14.5.6.2). Both processes can be combined if a function template competes with a non-template function, but in the cases discussed here, it's just two templates competing. I don't see how the conversion-sequence based ranking (which is for function overload, not template overload) applies there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the crux: Deducing a type from a braced-init-list (`{expr...}`) doesn't work for template arguments, only `auto`. With template arguments, you get a deduction failure, and the overload is removed from consideration. This leads to the first and third output.

> it does even matter whether one takes the `initializer_list` by value or by `const&`

`foo`: For any `X`, two overloads taking `X` and `X&` parameters are ambiguous for an lvalue argument - both are *equally viable* (same for `X` vs `X&&` for rvalues).

```
struct X{};
void f(X);
void f(X&);
X x;
f(x); // error: ambiguous overloads
```

However, partial ordering rules step in here (§14.5.6.2), and the function taking a generic `std::initializer_list` is *more specialized* than the generic one taking anything.

`goo`: For two overloads with `X&` and `X const&` parameters and a `X&` argument, the first one is *more viable* because the second overload requires a *Qualification conversion* from `X&` to `X const&` (§13.3.3.1.2/1 Table 12 and §13.3.3.2/3 third sub-bullet).

Comment: Sadly, the standard doesn't seem to specify what happens if the specialization criterion and the more viable criterion contradict each other on which function is to be used ...

Comment: @PierreBdR: It does, the cases for determining the *best viable function* are looked at in the order they appear in.

Answer (score 4):

If Scott really says that he's wrong, and it's another problem with the misleading "universal references" mental model he's teaching.

So-called "universal references" *are* greedy, and might match when you don't want or expect them to, but that doesn't mean they are always the best match.

Non-template overloads can be an exact match and will be preferred to the "universal reference", e.g. this selects the non-template

```
bool f(int) { return true; }
template<typename T> void f(T&&) { }
bool b = f(0);
```

And template overloads can be more specialized than the "universal reference" and so will be chosen by overload resolution. e.g.

```
template<typename T> struct A { };
template<typename T> void f(T&&) { }
template<typename T> bool f(A<T>) { return true; }
bool b = f(A<int>());
```

[DR 1164](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164) confirms that even `f(T&)` is more specialized than `f(T&&)` and will be preferred for lvalues.

In two of your cases the `initializer_list` overloads are not only more specialized, but a braced-init-list such as `{1,2,3}` can never be deduced by template argument deduction.

The explanation for your results is:

```
foo( {1,2,3} );
```

You cannot deduce a template argument from a braced-init-list, so deduction fails for `foo(T&&)` and `foo(initializer_list<int>)` is the only viable function.

```
foo( il );
```

`foo(initializer_list<T>)` is more specialized than `foo(T&&)` so is chosen by overload resolution.

```
goo( {1,2,3} );
```

You cannot deduce a template argument from a braced-init-list, so `goo(initializer_list<int>)` is the only viable function.

```
goo( il );
```

`il` is a non-const lvalue, `goo(T&&)` can be called with `T` deduced as `initializer_list<int>&`, so its signature is `goo(initializer_list<int>&)` which is a better match than `goo(initializer_list<int> const&)` because binding the non-const `il` to a const-reference is a worse conversion sequence than binding it to a non-const-reference.

One of the comments above quotes Scott's slides as saying: "Makes no sense: URefs handle everything."  That's true, and that's exactly why you might want to overload! You might want a more specific function for certain types, and the universal reference function for everything else.  You can also use SFINAE to constrain the universal reference function to stop it handling certain types, so that other overloads can handle them.

For an example in the standard library, `std::async` is an overloaded function taking universal references. One overload handles the case where the first argument is of type `std::launch` and the other overload handles everything else. SFINAE prevents the "everything else" overload from greedily matching calls that pass `std::launch` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first the reaction to `foo` makes sense. `initializer_list<T>` match both calls and is more specialized, therefore should be called this way.

For `goo`, this is in sync with perfect forwarding. when calling `goo(il)`, there is the choice between `goo(T&&)` (with `T = initializer_list<T>&`) and the constant reference version. I guess calling the version with the non-const reference has precedence over the more specialized version with the const reference. That being said, I am not sure this is a well defined situation w.r.t. the standard.

**Edit:**

Note that if there were no template, that would be resolved by the paragraph 13.3.3.2 (Ranking implicit conversion sequences) of the standard. The problem here is that, AFAIK, the partial ordering of template function would dictate the second (more specialized) `goo(initializer_list<T> const&)` is to be called, but the ranking on implicit conversion sequences would dictate that `goo(T&&)` is to be called. So I guess this is an ambiguous case.

Comment: @DyP: There are no non-template functions here.

Comment: @Xeo Oh, I'm too tired... yeah

Comment: @DyP I know, but templates complicate things. I added a note to explain that.

Comment: @PierreBdR: Implicit-conversion-sequences are handled before partial-ordering, making the first overload more viable.

Comment: @Xeo I guess you nailed it. Both conversion sequences are of rank "Exact Match", but [over.ics.rank]/3 explicitly prefers the conversion w/o qualification adjustment. [over.match.best]/1 states as you said that implicit conversion sequences are used before partial ordering to determine the best overload.

Comment: @DyP: Yep, the wording "or, if not that," at the end of every bullet should make it clear that they're looked at in order.

Comment: @Xeo I'd go with "Given these definitions, a viable function *F1* is defined to be a better function than another viable function
*F2* ***if*** for all arguments i, ICS*i*(F1) **is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then**" ;)